# Run java jar file recursively

Tags: linux, deployment

I have a deploy script that git pulls code from a repo.  I'd like to minify the javascript (js) and css files in that deploy script using yuicompressor.

In order to minify one js file you'd use something like this:

`java -jar yuicompressor-2.4.2.jar test.js -o test.js`

How can I do that to all js and css files recursively (inside subdirectories and across all files while excluding files that aren't js or css)?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `find + exec`

```
$ find . \( -iname *.js -o -iname *.css \) -exec java -jar /full/path/to/yuicompressor-2.4.2.jar {} -o {} \;
```

Run it on the root directory of where are your `.css` and `.js` are.